# How to update Cordova plugin in JDeveloper?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, jdeveloper, android-security

I have been working with JDeveloper for only a couple of months in order to develop an App for both: Android and iOS platforms.

Recently [Gfolks advice into the DevConsole that they are no longer supporting Cordova plugin previous to 4.1.1](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6325474)

I did not find any "How to" upgrade the Cordova plugins, I will appreciate if anyone could provide with any help.

Currently I'm using:
JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.1.3.0.0
MAF 2.1.1.0.41.150325.1239
Xcode version 6.4 (6E35b)
Android API 16 - 22